# Text limit inside <span> XHTML?

Tags: xhtml, limit, html

I would like to limit the text inside a  tag so when I add a new article in my ASP admin panel, it only has 350 characters max.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Do you want the limit to be effective when you submit your article or when you display it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with a tag, except if it's an input tag.

```
<input type="text" id="mytext" name="blah" maxlength="10" />
```

Of course you can make this limit using javascript or server side programing.

For instance, here is how to do it for a textarea : http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/form/limit-characters.html

Answer (score 0):

This depends how you ask the user for input. The `<input>` tag can have a [`maxlength`](http://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=4&ved=0CBMQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Ftags%2Fatt_input_maxlength.asp&ei=Du72SqH4DJOCmgOPqvChAw&usg=AFQjCNGayQBKEW-Iw1jfd77w1bTyTj6B6w) attribute which should be respected by the browsers.

[You can also use some client-side JavaScript to apply and notify the user of the limit](http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/form/limit-characters.html), but you still need to check it on the server before committing it to your database (as I assume you want to do), because for any reason you could still getmore characters in the request to the server (hand-crafted query etc.).